# Creating a Matrix View for Users to input numbers via TextField (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to construct a matrix where users can input numbers and do calculations. Currently, I have something like this:

```
@State var dimension = 2
@State var matrixVals = [Double]()

ForEach(0..<dimension, id:\.self) { index in
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        ForEach(0..<dimension, id:\.self) {i2 in
                            
                            TextField("", text: Binding(
                                get: { if matrixVals.count > index*i2 { return String(matrixVals[index*i2]) } else { return "" }},
                                set: { (newValue) in return self.matrixVals.append(Double(newValue) ?? 1.0) }
                            ))
                            
                            .background(Color.gray)
                            .frame(width: 35 - CGFloat(dimension*3), height: 55 - CGFloat(dimension*3), alignment: .center)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 12 - CGFloat(dimension))
                            .padding(.vertical, 0 - CGFloat(dimension/2))
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
```

Dimension can be increased/decreased by pressing a button, so it should be dynamic. This is what I get after inputting 7 on the first block (it copies it to every block in the first column and the row). Any idea where I went wrong (I think it's most likely related to my misuse of index and i2 as indices)?  [image]

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero multiplied by any number is still zero. Your bug is here:

```
index*i2
```

Instead , try this:

```
index*dimension + i2
```

Also, you can consider 2 dimensional array (a.k.a. Array of arrays). This may make things easier.

Comment: I assume it's because at first iteration, the outer loop index is 0 and thus the full row/column of the same numbers. Any ideas on how to fix it? Edit: just saw your comment. Will try that now. Thank you! Edit 2: It worked! Thank you so much.