# How do I create and link a matrix of Textfield

Tags: matrix, swiftui

I'm trying to create a Matrix of `TextField`'s to calculate Eigenvalues and -vectors of that matrix, with the size being in a range from 2-5 based on user input. I ended up using `ForEach` Loops for the creation, but still had issues with saving the input values until I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617517/creating-a-matrix-view-for-users-to-input-numbers-via-textfield-swiftui).
But this is leaving me with 3 major drawbacks:

1. I dont really understand how the `Binding(get: set:)` is working and havent found any helpful documentation on it. But somehow it is so quick in setting the values, that:
2. I cant enter numbers that are more than one digit, even when removing the default value in favor of force unwrapping and
3. Hence the pure `append` any correction attempts mess up the data

All attempt's regarding using an external Matrix structure, or a 2D-Array leave me blank when it comes to linking with the text Binding. So codewise I'm kind of stuck with my general planned layout, the picker and the non optimal solution:

```
import SwiftUI


struct Eigen: View {
    
    @State private var dimension = 3
    @State var matrixVals = [Double]()
    
        
    var body: some View {
        Text("Eigenwerte und Vektoren")
            .font(.largeTitle)
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("Bitte Matrix Größe wählen: ")
                Picker(selection: $dimension, label: Text("Dimension")) {
                    Text("2x2").tag(2)
                    Text("3x3").tag(3)
                    Text("4x4").tag(4)
                    Text("5x5").tag(5)
                }.frame(maxWidth:150)
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0..<dimension, id:\.self) { row in
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(0..<dimension, id:\.self) {column in
                                TextField("", text: Binding(
                                    get: { if matrixVals.count > column*dimension + row { return String(matrixVals[column*dimension + row]) } else { return "" }},
                                    set: { (newValue) in return self.matrixVals.append(Double(newValue) ?? 1.0) }
                                )).frame(maxWidth: 40, alignment: .center)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Aktualisieren", action: Auswertung)
            }
        }
    }
    func Auswertung(){
        for i in matrixVals{
            print("\(i)")
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go from here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Binding` is quite simple struct with getter and setter, views may use it differently depending on the realisation.

`TextField`(any most of apple views) calls:

1. `get` each time view is rebuilt
2. `set` after any text change.

What happens in your case:

1. You enter first character(lets say "1"), it's converted to double `1` and added to the array, as it's a @State this triggers view reload, textfield calls the `get` and you convert `1` to "1.0" (that's default string representation of double)
2. You enter second character, it appends it to the current string ("1.0" + "1"), so you're getting "1.01" into `set`, then you're appending it to the array and it becomes the second item
3. if you try to delete last char from "1.0", set will get "1." which is converted to double `1` and again back to string "1.0"

So in your `set` you wanna to update values of the array, not to append. And probably to fill it with empty strings so they can be edited in any order.

Also I suggest you to store values as strings so you won't have problem with converting them, and you can change text color to red if string can't be converted to double(and maybe disable the button)

```
struct Eigen: View {
    
    @State private var dimension = 3
    @State var matrixVals = [String](repeating: "", count: 9)
        
    var body: some View {
        Text("Eigenwerte und Vektoren")
            .font(.largeTitle)
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("Bitte Matrix Größe wählen: ")
                Picker(selection: $dimension, label: Text("Dimension")) {
                    Text("2x2").tag(2)
                    Text("3x3").tag(3)
                    Text("4x4").tag(4)
                    Text("5x5").tag(5)
                }.frame(maxWidth:150)
                .onChange(of: dimension) { dimension in
                    // add new empties if new dimension is bigger then prev
                    let extraValues = dimension * dimension - matrixVals.count
                    if extraValues > 0 {
                        matrixVals.append(.init(repeating: "", count: extraValues))
                    }
                }
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0..<dimension, id:\.self) { row in
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(0..<dimension, id:\.self) {column in
                                let index = column*dimension + row
                                TextField("title", text: Binding(
                                    get: { matrixVals[index] },
                                    set: { newValue in
                                        self.matrixVals[index] = newValue
                                    }
                                )).frame(maxWidth: 40, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(Double(matrixVals[index]) != nil ? .black : .red)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
                Spacer()
                Button("Aktualisieren", action: Auswertung)
            }
        }
    }
    func Auswertung(){
        for i in matrixVals{
            print("\(i)")
        }
    }
}
```